# Retrieving child records from firebase using unique auto-generated keys

Tags: angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Scenario is,

Our data on firebase is structured as shown below

[image]

Image is based on sample database where post1,post2 under Posts node are randomly generated keys just like "YyhsyyHyzhh-Ke" etc and comment1,comment2 also randomly generated keys.

My problem is that I want to fetch all posts and related comments from firebase and as you can see under post1,there is a comments node which contains keys of comments related to post1 but im unable to get keys of comments so that I can browse to that comment's text

see below code

```
    appMainModule.controller('GetCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', function ($scope, $firebase) {






         var firebaseObj = new Firebase("FirebaseURL/Posts");

         var sync = $firebase(firebaseObj);
        $scope.articles=sync.$asArray();

  $scope.articles.$loaded(function (data) {
         var mainVar ;
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             mainVar = data[i];
             var commentsWithIds=mainVar.Comments;
             //how to fetch keys side of data from commentsWithIds as I dont know rendomly generated keys

         }
         });
```

I want get comments keys so that I cloud make URL like this new Firebase("FirebaseURL/Comments"+CommentsAutoGeneratedKey) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question well, you can use [**`Object.keys()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method:

```js
var comments = {  
  "comment1":{  
    "text":"this is first comment"
  },
  "comment2":{  
    "text":"this is 2nd comment"
  },
  "comment3":{  
    "text":"this is third comment"
  }
};

console.log(Object.keys(comments));
```

Comment: thanks it works. for the time being i will use it. but im not sure wether is this a better way beacuase $firbaseObject.$id, $on,$once function also provides ways to get keys but im unable to use them in my angularfire project as it gives me error that function is not defined.